# Mysql Table onmouseover display specific value

Tags: jquery, mysql

I have a webpage that displays a table with values from mysql database. One value is represented by an icon and when I click the icon the value pops up in a popup window...I would prefer to mouseover or hover and display the value in an info box that appears near the mouse pointer. It works great as is and on mouseover a popup appears with the specific value and onmouseout it disappears.
What can I do to have hover box appear instead of a popup

```
<td align="center">
    <a href="#" onMouseOver="openPopUp('info_formz.php?`enter code here`id=$rows[id]', 'popup', 200, 20);" onMouseOut=" closePopUp('info_formz.php?id=$rows[id]')">
        <img src=backgrounds" . $rows['complete'] . ".png border="0">
    </a>
</td>
```

Here is the script that makes it work

```
<script>
<!--
function openPopUp(url, name, w, h)
{
    // Fudge factors for window decoration space.
    // In my tests these work well on all platforms & browsers.
    w += 32;
    h += 96;
    win = window.open(url,
        name,
        'width=' + w + ', height=' + h + ', ' +
        'location=no, menubar=no, ' +
        'status=no, toolbar=no, scrollbars=yes, resizable=no');
    win.resizeTo(w, h);
    win.focus();
}

function closePopUp() {
    win.close();
}

// -->
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best would be to use a plugin such as http://qtip2.com/.

Here's a small example:

```js
$('[data-tooltip!=""]').qtip({ 
    content: {
        attr: 'data-tooltip' 
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/qtip2/2.2.1/basic/jquery.qtip.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/qtip2/2.2.1/basic/jquery.qtip.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<td align="center">
    <a href="#" data-tooltip="Some very cool informative stuff goes in here.">
        <img src=backgrounds.png border="0">
    </a>
</td>
```

### EDIT

Answer to your comment. Have a look at their documentation on [loading content via ajax](http://qtip2.com/plugins#ajax).

Using the same layout as above, an example:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('[data-tooltip]').each(function() {
        $(this).qtip({
            content: {
                text: function(event, api) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'info_formz.php', // Use data-url attribute for the URL
                        data: {
                            id: $(this).attr('data-tooltip')
                        }
                    }).then(function(content) {
                        // Set the tooltip content upon successful retrieval
                        api.set('content.text', content);
                    }, function(xhr, status, error) {
                        // Upon failure... set the tooltip content to the status and error value
                        api.set('content.text', status + ': ' + error);
                    });

                    return 'Loading...'; // Set some initial text
                }
            }
        });
    })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/qtip2/2.2.1/basic/jquery.qtip.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/qtip2/2.2.1/basic/jquery.qtip.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<td align="center">
    <a href="#" data-tooltip="<?= $rows[id]; ?>">
        <img src=backgrounds.png border="0">
    </a>
</td>
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice, since I know nothing about qtip and have been reading the info is there a good example somewhere of how to call a value back from table onmouseover.  My page displays multiple rows and when I hover over each the specific icon in each row the value should be returned in a box.  Thanks

Comment: Thank you, working my way slowly though this. Where do I put the ......$('[data-tooltip!=""]').qtip({ .......... does it go between tags like <script> etc?  Sorry for being so stupid. Also in qtip do I add the qtip package files to the directory where the page is located?  By package files I mean the files qtip asks you to download once you select what you want from main page.  Appreciate the help and patience

Comment: So here is what I have         <a href="#" data-tooltip="<info_formz.php?id=$rows[id]; ?>">   and I put the function inbetween <script> tags  anything I need or am doing wrong...also I cant figure out how to properly post these elements again  :P  Man I suck

Comment: Also I cannot figure how to post proper response here with code in it...I suck, sorry for that

Comment: `$rows['id']` is all that you need to put in the data-tooltip bit. You don't need to put `info_formz.php` in there, as it's already hitting that URL.

Comment: Thank you, for helping me understand that.  So, I have put the code in between <script> tags and when I hover nothing is displaying, do I need further files etc.. put into the file path  ie jquery.qtip.min.js
jquery.qtip.css
jquery.qtip.js
jquery.qtip.min.css ?  I do appreciate the help

Comment: Issue solved, thanks greatly to DarkRanger, amazing person